# Equivalent Sqlite DATETIME('now','localtime') in Flask SQLAlchemy

Tags: python, flask, sqlite, flask-sqlalchemy

If I have following order in raw sqlite in flask app :

```
g.db.execute("INSERT INTO tbl_email (name,email,message,timestamp,was_sent,place,read) VALUES (?,?,?,DATETIME('now','localtime'),?,?,?)", db_save)
```

What is Equivalent in flask sqlalchemy for inserting `DATETIME('now','localtime')

Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Flask-SQLAlchemy you'd have set the model like this:

```
class Foo(db.Model):
  date_time = db.Column(db.DateTime(timezone=True), default=datetime.datetime.utcnow)
```

Maybe replacing `datetime.datetime.utcnow` for a function that returns your local time. SQLAlchemy takes charge of setting the value upon save.